# Can I create a homemade zoom lens for the Fujifilm Instax Mini 7?

Tags: fujifilm, polaroid, instant-camera

I would like to take zoomed photos with the Fujifilm Instax Mini 7. What would I need to do in order to create an external lens to add in front of the one that's already there?

Answer (score 1):

Holga makes a 2.5x tele add-on lens for their K200-NM camera. They also make an [adapter + 2.5x tele kit specifically for the Instax Mini 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005OFK8NK) (Amazon US link).

Comment: Get them while they're hot. As of November 2015, Holga is no longer making anything.